# Kendogrid destroy() and recreate the table on a new datasource, why do the old table columns still exist?

Tags: telerik, kendo-ui, telerik-grid, kendo-grid

When invoking `destroy()` in KendoUI Grid and then recreate the table on a new `DataSource`: why do the old table columns still exist?

The only element here that stays the say is the element. How do I tell the grid to read the new datasource columns (it reads everything else correct).

(if I make 2 different elements, they both populate properly but I rather just keep 1 element and replace the elements table by destroy and reinit)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Most probably this is because you are not clearing the content inside the Grid container. e.g.

```
$('#gridName').data().kendoGrid.destroy();
$('#gridName').empty();
```

or shorter syntax

```
$('#gridName').kendoGrid('destroy').empty();
```

Other way the Grid takes into account the old html that is left - do not forget that the Grid could be initialized from table like [here](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/from-table.html).

Comment: I end up with a Javascript runtime error: Unable to get property 'kendoGrid' of undefined or null reference. When I try to execute the above mentioned javascript.

Answer (score 3):

Just want to clarify on the last bit of Peter Subev's answer because it helped me:

> "do not forget that the Grid could be initialized from table like [here](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/from-table.html)"

This is just saying that in your HTML you used a `<table>` tag rather than a `<div>` tag. Using a `<table>` tag separates the Grid table data from the Grid columns, so when you do $('#gridName').kendoGrid('destroy').empty() it is only destroying/emptying the table data and not the column information.

Switch your HTML `<table>` tag to a `<div>` tag to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working in the angular framework and can't seem to reinit the Kendo grid with a new dataSource and new columns. Nothing works on the 2nd grid init. I've tried:

```
  if (vm.mainHierGrid != null) {
            //vm.mainHierGrid.data().kendoGrid.destroy();
            $('#mainGrid').data().kendoGrid.destroy();
            //$('#mainGrid').empty();
            vm.mainHierGrid.destroy();
        }
```

Comment: I had the same issue, I ended up using the grid in jQuery embedded in an angular directive

Answer (score 1):

Destroy kendo grid and rebind it

```
if ($('#kgCopyEntityGrid').hasClass("k-grid")) {
                    $('#kgCopyEntityGrid').kendoGrid('destroy').empty();
                }

                var kgCopyGrid = $("#kgCopyEntityGrid").kendoGrid({
// your code here
                }).data("kendoGrid");
```