# Enable/Disable sortable on specify column in kendo ui grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sorting, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a kendo ui grid on my page.
And I have a button too. I want when I click button, sortable property on a specify column disable, and when click the button again, sortable property enable.

How to I do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Runtime enabling/disabling the sorting feature of the Grid is not supported.
But you can find some approaches to achieve it here: http://www.telerik.com/forums/disable-or-remove-sortable-capability-on-column-with-rebuilding-entire-grid

Hope this link will help you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method for this - this is option which is set only upon initialziation. So you will need to re-initialize the whole Grid. Covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15618467/kendogrid-destroy-and-recreate-the-table-on-a-new-datasource-why-do-the-old-t/15624325#15624325).

The column.sortable option should be set to true/false depending on the button that was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write an click event for a table header on javascript.This event will prevent click on table header.

```
 $(".k-grid-header .k-link").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).text() === Header Name) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
    });
```

e.PreventDefault helps to avoid window jump to top when clicking #-links.
Give your headername into the if condition to which you want to disable sorting

Comment: not sure this is going to solve the problem - he wants a to have a toggle switch for the sortable property.

Comment: this is only for disable sorting of specific column